# populate bootstrap modal with data from php page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is there something wrong on the ajax I have? get_details.php does not load on the modal

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    $.ajax
    ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "get_details.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(r)
       {
          $("#detail").html(r);
       } 
    });
});
```

Let's just say I have this inside get_details.php. I want to make "test" to be on the modal

```
<?php echo "test";?>
```

Here is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="detail">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check what do you get as a response `console.log(r)`

Comment: Also I think, the `type: POST` is wrong since you want to `GET` something, not posting.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam is right, whats the return response of ajax?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam there is no response. I have checked the request status from the Developer Tools and it shows a 404 status

Comment: Then URL that you are trying is not found. check the URL twice. give `full url` rather than just file name

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Thamaraiselvam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned `HTTP 404`

Give full URL 
For example `http://localhost/yourapp/get_details.php`

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    $.ajax
    ({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://localhost/yourapp/get_details.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(r)
       {
          $("#detail").html(r);
       } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont have comment privilege, hence writing in answer.
Check XHR request status in Network tab of Developer Tools(F12), whether it is calling get_details.php or not?

Also JFYI, "show.bs.modal" event will fire before opening of the modal and "shown.bs.modal" will fire when the modal is opened.

Comment: It is calling get_details.php but the status is 404 @pravindot17

Comment: it means the file was'nt in the same directory of your script as you have mentioned "url:get_details.php"